# JavaScript addition issue

Tags: javascript, math

So, i'm adding 2 characters 4 levels together (hp, attack, strength and defense) and then comparing them. However I am having a problem. when the numbers are added together they're added together as a string so it outputs as follows. 9060951/99709940 instead of 246 (90+60+95+1)/308 (99+70+99+40). Here is what I am doing.

```
function calculate(player1, player2) {
    var total1 = player1.getTotal();
    var total2 = player2.getTotal();
    var differencePercentage;

    if(total1 > total2) {
        differencePercentage = total2 + "/" + total1 + " = " + (total2/total1);
    } else {
        differencePercentage = total1 + "/" + total2 + " = " + (total1/total2);
    }



    var percentage = differencePercentage;

    return percentage;
}

function Player(hp, attack, strength, defense) {
    this.hp = parseInt(hp);
    this.attack = parseInt(attack);
    this.strength = parseInt(strength);
    this.defense = parseInt(defense);

    this.getTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        total = hp + attack + strength + defense;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

You are parsing the Ints into `this.hp`, `this.attack` etc. in your `Player` function but not into the `getTotal` function

Try this

```
this.getTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;
    total = this.hp + this.attack + this.strength + this.defense;
    return total;
}
```